# Regex in Java vs Scala discrepancy. Same code/logic, different output

Tags: java, regex, scala

I was converting existing Scala code that uses regex to check if an input has any target words/phrases/strings in it. I know there exists helper functions like `contains` or `substring` but a regex solution is needed.

Here is the scala code:

```scala
val NonCharacter: String = "[^\\p{L}\\p{M}]"
val targetWord = "phone"

var regexMiddle = s".*(${NonCharacter}${targetWord}${NonCharacter}).*"
var regexLeft = s"(${targetWord}${NonCharacter}).*"
var regexRight = s".*(${NonCharacter}${targetWord})"
var regexSame = s"(${targetWord})"
var exactRegex = s"${regexMiddle}|${regexLeft}|${regexRight}|${regexSame}"

"My phone is blue".matches(exactRegex) // returns true (EXPECTED)
"i have 1 phone".matches(exactRegex) // returns true (EXPECTED)
"phone2".matches(exactRegex)  // return false (EXPECTED)
"phone!".matches(exactRegex)  // return false (EXPECTED)
"phone ".matches(exactRegex)  // return false (EXPECTED)
```

Here is the java code:

```java
String nonCharacter = "[^\\p{L}\\p{M}]";
String targetWord = "phone";

String regexMiddle = String.format(".*(%s%s%s).*", nonCharacter, targetWord, nonCharacter);
String regexLeft = String.format("(%s%s).*", targetWord, nonCharacter);
String regexRight = String.format(".*(%s%s)", nonCharacter, targetWord);
String regexSame = String.format("(%s)", targetWord);
String exactRegex = String.format("%s|%s|%s|%s", regexMiddle, regexLeft, regexRight, regexSame);

System.out.print("My phone is blue".matches(exactRegex)); // returns true (EXPECTED)
System.out.print("i have 1 phone".matches(exactRegex)); // returns true (EXPECTED)
System.out.print("phone2".matches(exactRegex)); // returns true (NOT EXPECTED)
System.out.print("phone!".matches(exactRegex)); // returns true (NOT EXPECTED)
System.out.print("phone ".matches(exactRegex)); // returns true (NOT EXPECTED)
```

Any idea why this discrepancy exists and how to handle unseen edge-cases?

Comment: I don't understand the scala behavior. All marked as "not expected" match because of regexLeft which is part of exactRegex.

Comment: You should use Pattern.quote(targetWord) in case it contains any regex special characters. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Your expectations are quite strange:

```
"phone2".matches("phone[^\\p{L}\\p{M}]"); // returns true (NOT EXPECTED)
"phone!".matches("phone[^\\p{L}\\p{M}]"); // returns true (NOT EXPECTED)
"phone ".matches("phone[^\\p{L}\\p{M}]"); // returns true (NOT EXPECTED)
```

`"2"`, `"!"`, `" "` - are NOT letters and are NOT marks. Thus I would expect `true` as a result for such validations. And question is - why Scala treats these characters as letter or mark.

> \p{L} or \p{Letter}: any kind of letter from any language
>
> \p{M} or \p{Mark}: a character intended to be combined with another character (e.g. accents, umlauts, enclosing boxes, etc.)

Source: [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category).